# Protractor: All of a sudden getting error Element is not visible

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

I wrote a test to select a login button in a pop up window that is an okta widget. About 2 hours ago my test was working fine and the button was being clicked. All of a sudden, protractor says it is not visible. I have not modified to code in any way which leaves me extremely confused. I have spent a while trying to get it to work again but every time I get the same error, even if the element is obviously visible. My test should click the button then redirect the user to a sign in page. For some reason this button is now not visible. Here is the line that is in my template file for the button.

```
 <button class = 'loginBtn' mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated" (click)="oktaAuth.loginRedirect()"> Login </button>
```

In the page source, on chrome, here is the extended code for the button:

```
<button _ngcontent-c5="" class="loginBtn mat-raised-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" color="primary" mat-raised-button="" ng-reflect-color="primary" style=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper"> Login </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

Here is how I am references the button in my object class:

```
 getLoginBtn() {
return element(by.className('loginBtn'));
```

I even wrote code to find the pop-up window and then click the button, but I still get the not visible error. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Have no idea why my orignal code stopped working but I solved it doing this:

```
  getLogin() {
return element.all(by.cssContainingText('.mat-button-wrapper', ' Login ')).last();
```

I honestly have no clue what caused my original method to stop working but at least I found a solution. I have two of the same widgets, one that displays in a pop up, and one that displays on my homepage within a sidebar. I created a separate class for my pop up login so that it would be more efficient, but for some reason that stopped working. Since my other button worked, I just used the class name these two buttons have, and applied .all and .last() so that protractor would click the last button.

Comment: Did your code stop working after you added the second widget?

Comment: No the second widget was already there. Code was unchanged. Focused on another project for an hour. When I came back to this project, the test wasn't working.